# Does initial node positions of a graph affect asymptotic graph disposition in ForceAtlas2 algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to visualize my graph with [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) which provides [ForceAtlas2 algorithm plugin](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2) for graph drawing.

What I'm wondering is if initial position (x and y coordinates) of nodes affects on asymptotic result graph disposition.

I'm using this algorithm plugin without any deep understanding so I was putting nodes with initial coordinates to roughly draw a blueprint of my objective graph shape in my own algorithm and then let *ForceAtlas2 algorithm* to adjust and beautify it.

If initial disposition of a graph doesn't affect result graph shape generated by ForceAtlas2, then I won't have to do unnecessary calculations for setting those initial coordinates.

Comment: Even if they don't affect the end position, notice that it's an asymptotic result. So if you start with meaningful coordinates, the algorithm might converge much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - check out [the documentation](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0098679):

> The force-directed drawing has the specificity of placing each node
>   depending on the other nodes. This process depends only on the
>   connections between nodes. Eventual attributes of nodes are never
>   taken into account. This strategy has its drawbacks. The result varies
>   depending on the initial state. The process can get stuck in a local
>   minimum. It is not deterministic, and the coordinates of each point do
>   not reflect any specific variable. The result cannot be read as a
>   Cartesian projection. The position of a node cannot be interpreted on
>   its own, it has to be compared to the others.

For one example, take two nodes connected by an edge.  FA2 will alter the distance between them, but will not affect the angle the edge makes with the horizontal, so this depends on the initial values

For a more interesting example, take a system of five nodes, O, A, B, C, and D, with connections O-A, O-B, O-C, and O-D.  One asymptotic position would have O at the origin, with A, B, C and D forming a four-pointed star around it.  Another would have the points in order B, A, C and D.  So again, the result depends on the initial conditions, but this time can't be easily transformed.